# OpenAM not loading after admin login

Tags: authentication, admin, openam

Trying to explore OpenAM(OpenAM-13.0.0) with tomcat 8 installation successful but when logged in as amadmin from long time getting the screen below
[image]

tried following the solution from here

```
https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-6785
```

but no luck still did not work

tried installing chrome dev same issue

Enabled cookies as well but still working

stuck form long time please help

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the version of OpemAM , tried with openAM 14 all worked well